# Connection failed while connecting JConsole on Windows with remote Java Springboot app on Linux

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, jmx, jconsole

I am starting the Java SpringBoot app on my **RHEL server having java 1.8** installed with the following command:-

```
java -jar App.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev -Xms96m -Xmx128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:loggc.log 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5901
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=5901
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```

When the jar has started successfully, a **PID** has been assigned and I wanted to **monitor that PID for Heap Utilisation**. So I am trying to achieve this by **using JConsole on windows environment** and binding the JMX port on Linux with a port on windows using Port Forwarding using putty.

But I am not able to connect successfully as there is a JRMP Connection failure.

Can someday give me an insight on what I might be doing wrong or if there is any better way to analyze the heap utilization in Linux environment.

I tried to access it via: jconsole 5901 but it says Non-JRMP server at the remote endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the arguments is wrong. The arguments are available in as args in your main method, but Java runtime doesn't care about them.

```
java -h
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
```

With correct ordering, Java runtime will pickup the arguments and not your application.

```sh
java -Xms96m -Xmx128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:loggc.log 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5901
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=5901
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
-jar App.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

Comment: Thanks but now receiving a different error -> Do I need to open a tcp port with 5901 as mentioned jmx port on linux since it says Error: JMX connector server communication error: service:jmx:rmi://ip:5901

Comment: I was able to start application now successfully and jmx ports is being binded with windows but jconsole still not able to connect.

Comment: @Mangla Specify your IP address instead of locahost for the args  `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname`. (e.g) `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.8.252`